# Failed to start LightDM

Tags: debian

I restarted my Debian Virtualbox (Debian 8, virtualized on a windows 10 machine) I get this message about 3 times:

```
[FAILED] to start Light Display Manager.
```

So, going into the text-based boot menu, I type "systemctl status lightdm". Here is the result: 
[code=exited, status=1/FAILURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llFF.png)

I don't really know why. I've been trying to start it up for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it was a clustertruck of madness that broke permissions, rc.local, init.d, and other things. So, I just reset the system.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, resetting ***lightdm.conf*** to default one (the package-supplied version in /etc/defaults/ or wherever it is located) is a really efficient way to resolve such kind of problems. They do change something a little on a regular basis.
This approach has had helped me number of times already.

---

As for me, the most common problem ended being some resolution configuration, font or theme configuration parameter being the problem preventing lightdm to start

Comment: Nope. Completely reset the config file and restarted it.

Comment: I've had hit this sh*t vent on ArchLinux and Gentoo few times, while LightDM is from Ubuntu...
Most of times it ended with bad config _or_ dependent libraries badly specified within lightdm package..
There should be one like lightdm-gdm as well...
I've got no better ideas elsewise unfortunately.
LightDM is always a real PITA for me as well, if this can encourage you.
You should consider switching to https://launchpad.net/lightdm
There are 1-2 log configuration parameters in LightDM you might look into, yet those has never helped me much (Because of log output not helpful at all)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llFF.png is the output of doing systemctl status lightdm